# Java Scanner and console input redirect

Tags: java, redirect, console, java.util.scanner, stdin

Stdin redirect breaks with simple Java (20.0.1) program using Scanner on Mac.

Error: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

*Broken.java*

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
class Broken {
    public static String getUserName() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        return s.nextLine();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = getUserName();
        String b = getUserName();
    }
}
```

*names.txt*

```
Bob
Lisa
```

*Bash Command Line*

```
javac Broken.java 
java Broken < names.txt
```

This shouldn't crash, but it does with a NoSuchElementException. I don't want to know other ways of solving this problem. I want to know why this fails. Is the stdin steam being closed by Scanner? What else could it be?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good use of time commenting on 'surprising' results when the *code itself* is surprising. Why, for instance, would you read the user name *twice* from a redirected file?

Comment: So, when teaching (usually Python), I often ask students to take a piece of functionality and move it to a separate method. In this case, we take user interaction, move it to a method, then add more stuff (like input validation). This serves as a little piece of encapsulation. I build auto graders to test student code, and typically feed input from files for rapid testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you reopen scanner each time, essentially using a different input stream each time.  So subsequent streams would hit an end of file. Open the scanner only once and not in `getUserName`.  And in general I don't usually prompt in input methods.  As in this case it doesn't make sense to prompt when taking input from a file.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Broken {
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static String getUserName() {
       
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        return s.nextLine();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = getUserName();
        String b = getUserName();
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

When run as `java Broken < names.txt`
prints

```
Enter Name: Bob
Enter Name: Lisa
```

Comment: It's a pity you removed the comment about the redirect, as now, the problem has been cast in quite a different light

Comment: @g00se Actually, I don't remember making any comments.  I did alter some text in my answer regarding that it doesn't make sense to prompt for input when reading from a file.  But then I realized that the getUserName method could also be used for regular user input requests.  Probably would be best to just not prompt in the method.

Comment: afaicr you said something along the lines of "you don't need to prompt if you're going to read from a redirect". Lack of a prompt otherwise would just cause confusion in the user.

Comment: @g00se Yes I said that.  But the method could be used for interactive input too so I removed it.  Since you considered it meaningful I have put the text back in my answer.

Comment: It's just a small example for students to learn basics. I am redirecting input from files for auto grading purposes.

Comment: What does "essentially discarding the input stream" mean. Stdin should never be closed. The garbage collector shouldn't run for such a small program. I don't get why it fails. There are obviously much better ways to too this, but we educators like to start simple.

Comment: @Siva At the command line, you redirect once so it has started. You prompt for username which works once. Then when you open a new Scanner for the second username. That is a different stream, not the redirected one. So it hits an eof and throws an exception. If you kept on using the same instance of scanner it would have worked.  I modified my answer to provide a better explanation.

Comment: @WSJ "I presume that since the input was buffered, it was already in the current streams input buffer" is the answer I was looking for. This explanation makes sense. Thanks for your input. I will simply find a different example for students at the beginning of the semester (as class variables come later). Thanks!

Comment: Just to be clear, `System.in` is an `InputStream` which isn't buffered.  But subsequent underpinnings of the Scanner class do create a buffer.

Comment: @Siva *`will simply find a different example for students at the beginning of the semester (as class variables come later).`*  Well, you could create a local scanner instance in main and then pass that instance to the `getUserName` method.